# Delete create button from second view

Tags: python, odoo

I have this student class with a many2many relation with subject class, when opening the subject table, I want the user to only add existing subjects and cannot create a new one.
This is in the student form:

```
<notebook> 
    <page string="subjects"> 
        <field name="subject_ids" nolabel="1"  options="'no_quick_create':True,'no_create_edit':True}" attrs="{'readonly':[('state','=','done')]}"/> 
    </page> 
</notebook>
```

I tried no_quick_create and no_create_edit but the create button keeps showing up

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: A possible way: you should create user groups, and the groups has differently permission. If the user has not permission, he can't create.
[This description](http://webkul.com/blog/openerp-security-permissions/) is useful from that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

create =  false #'it will not allow to create new value from the dropdown'

create_edit = false #'it will not allow to edit the value from the dropdown'

no_open = true #'it will restrict the popup (to parent window) from the current screen. specially for many2one fields'

```
<form string="My_Module" version="7.0">
  <notebook> 
    <page string="subjects"> 
      <field name="subject_ids" nolabel="1" attrs="{'readonly':[('state','=','done')]}" options="{'create': false, 'create_edit': false,'no_open': True}"/> 
    </page>
  </notebook>
```